# Append CSV cell based user input

Tags: python, csv

Require help: I have a CSV file named 'file_name.csv' containing data as mentioned below. I am building a small bank project (for self-learning) in which  I have used :

function open_account - computer asks name and generate random 3 digit account_number and stores it in CSV file

function existing_holder - computer asks account_number and display name which is already stored using open_account function And give the option to deposit or withdraw money

function deposit - computer asks amount to be deposited. And I want it should get appended in particular account_number which he has entered in existing_holder function and display balance.

Output expected: User enter account_number in existing_holder function and the computer asks amount to be deposited and it adds in particular account_number, account_balance

Please correct me what to use in deposit(). I tried using DicWriter, reader, converting them it list but didn't get code working.

Error: TypeError: 'DictWriter' object is not iterable

```
account_holder_name,    account_number, account_balance
Ganesh, 12345,  100
Parvati,    23456,  10000
Waheguru,   98765,  12098
```

I used below code:

```
import random as r
import csv
class Account():
    print("Welcome to AV Bank")
    def __init__(self,choice):
        self.choice = choice
        self.account_number = 0
        self.file_name = 'file_name.csv'
        self.header = ('account_holder_name', 'account_number', 'account_balance')


        def open_account(self):
        self.new_account_holder_name = str(input("Enter new account holder name: "))
        self.account_number = r.randrange(999)
        self.new_account_deposit = int(input("To open new a/c, deposit minimum Rs.1000/-: "))
        if self.new_account_deposit>=1000:
            with open(self.file_name, 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
                write_to_file = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=self.header)
               # write_to_file.writeheader()
                write_to_file.writerow(
                    {'account_holder_name': self.new_account_holder_name, 'account_number': self.account_number,
                     'account_balance': self.new_account_deposit})
            print(f"Mr.{self.new_account_holder_name} your a/c has been opened and a/c no. is {self.account_number}, With balance Rs. {self.new_account_deposit}/-")

        else:
            print("Deposit minimum Rs. 1000/-")

    def existing_holder(self):
        self.account_number = int(input("Enter account holder number: "))
        with open(self.file_name, 'r+') as csvfile:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in csv_reader:
                for acn in (row['account_number']):
                    if int(row['account_number']) == self.account_number:
                        print(f"Welcome Mr.{row['account_holder_name']}.Please select : \nPress 1 deposit money \nPress 2 for withdraw money")
                    break
            # else:
            #     print("Enter correct a/c number")

        def deposit(self):
        self.amount_added = int(input("Enter the amount to be deposited: "))
        with open(self.file_name, 'a+') as file:
            writeData = csv.DictWriter(file,fieldnames = self.header)

       ''' WANT TO ITERATE THE CSV FILE TO GET VALUE self.account_number AND UPDATE self.account_balance AFTER DOING ADDITION OPERATION''

        # for self.account_number in line:
        #     if line[self.account_number] == self.account_number:
        #         print("God")
        # with open(self.file_name, 'a+',newline='') as csvfile:
        #     csv_append = csv.reader(csvfile)
        #     line = list(csv_append)
        #
        #     print(line)
            #self.header = next(csv_append)
            # for row in csv_append:
            #     #self.balance = int(row['account_balance']
            #     for acn in (row['account_number']):
            #         if int(row['account_number']) == self.account_number:
            #             self.balance = int(row['account_balance'])
            #             self.new_balance = int(row['account_balance']) + self.amount_added
            #             csv_append.writerow(self.new_balance)
            #             print(f"Added Rs. {row['account_balance']} in account number {row['account_number']}")
            #             print(f"A/c balance is Rs.{self.balance}")
            #         break
            # else:
                #print("Enter correct a/c number")


customer_visit = int(input("Press 1: To Open New Bank Account or Press 2: To Use Existing Account : "))
acct1 = Account(customer_visit)
if customer_visit ==1:
    acct1.open_account()
if customer_visit ==2:
    acct1.existing_holder()
    holder_option = int(input())
    if holder_option ==1:
        acct1.deposit()
```

Comment: Your problem is in this line `r = list(readData)`. You are trying to iterate over the object and put these items in a list, which you can't do. Have you read the csv documentation for reading from files?

Comment: @incarnadine - I was trying but it failed. Please suggest alternative

Comment: have you tried `csv.reader(csvfile)` as the value of `readData` and then leaving the rest of your code as is

Comment: @incarnadine - want to iterate the csv file to get value of self.account_number AND UPDATE self.account_balance after doing addition operation. I need to get the value in csv and do addition

Comment: As people have said on your many other posts on this topic (and is clearly shown in the documentation), you need to make both a reader and a writer.

Comment: @incarnadine: Thanks for guiding me. I tried to change the code. I am successfully reading it, but on writing it is throwing error. How to append new balance in CSV

Comment: As shown in the documentation, use a writer to write/append